# html link in white without using css

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am new to html and I need to know how to make a text link appear in white without using css.

```
<h3><font color="white"><a href="index.html"> Home </a> & <a href="contact.html"> Contact <a> </font></h3>
```

This code only gives the ampersand sign in white.

Comment: All styling appears only in CSS. `color=white` is also CSS of some kind.

Comment: You need CSS for this: `a{color:white;}`, you can do it without creating a css document, with inline styling, but you still use CSS: `<a href="link" style="color:white;">Home</a>`

Comment: Why do you want to avoid CSS?

Comment: without using css or without using external css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `<a>` element has its own colour, you have to put the `<font>` inside the `<a>`.

```css
body {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<h3>
  <a href="index.html">
    <font color="white"> Home </font>
  </a>
  <font color="white">&amp;</font>
  <a href="contact.html">
    <font color="white"> Contact </font>
  </a>
</h3>
```

---

This is, of course, really horrible. This is why we've had CSS for over two decades. Use CSS.